# How to add and center a category search bar in menu nav?

Tags: html, css, search, menu

I have created a dropdown menu and a search bar with categories (like Amazon) and I'm trying to merge them, but with bad results. Could you help me centering the following search-box into the menu bar?

Here is the code of the menu:

```css
.fa {
  line-height: 1em;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
/*hack stack-overflow*/

ul::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li.left {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
li.right {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
li#login {
  position: relative;
}
li#login form {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
li#login:hover form {
  display: block;
}
input.login_field {
  margin: 10px;
}
#submit-div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="left"><a class="fa fa-home" href="index.jsp">&nbsp;Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="left"><a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="#home">&nbsp;Carrello</a>
    </li>

    <li id="search">
    </li>

    <li class="right"><a class="fa fa-user-plus" href="">&nbsp;Signup</a>
    </li>
    <li id="login" class="right">
      <a class="fa fa-sign-in" href="">&nbsp;Login</a>
      <form id="login_form" action="login" method="post">
        <input id="login_username" class="login_field" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
        <br />
        <input id="login_password" class="login_field" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
        <br />
        <div id="submit-div">
          <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and here the code of the search box:

```css
$border-color:orange;
 #form-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}
.nav-list {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
#dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
}
#dropdown:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.current-selection {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.in-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
#search-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
#search-box:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.go-button {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.go-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 115, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="form-wrapper">
  <button class="go-button fa fa-search"></button>
  <span class="nav-list">
  <span class="current-selection">
  </span>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="books-and-ebooks">Books & eBooks</option>
    <option value="audiobooks">Audiobooks</option>
    <option value="dvds">DVDs</option>
    <option value="other-resources">Other Resources</option>
    <option value="random">Random</option>
  </select>
  </span>
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <input type="text" name="query" id="search-box">
  </div>
</div>
```

However the search box looks different (better) on codepen: [enter link description here](http://codepen.io/1z10/pen/QEbjBx)

Comment: How do you want them merged? My current answer only fixes the search part. Could you give us more info on what you want?

Comment: Thanks, I would like to position the search bar in the center of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

This what you're after?

The problem with the search bar on Codepen was that on Codepen the CSS is complied as SCSS

You'll note that the CSS on Codepen says `CSS (SCSS)` and there is a small `View Complied` button to the right of it. Clicking on that will give you the CSS, and by using that you get the results below.

As to the menu, I've combined the two, but to be blunt, your html is somewhat flawed - I've added a min-width to the search bar otherwise it wont show up, and I hope you aren't planning to use this on mobiles otherwise you have a problem.

But it works - hope that's what you wanted!

Remember - the width of preview on here breaks it - click full page and you will see what you wanted.

```css
.fa {
  line-height: 1em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}


/*hack stack-overflow*/

ul::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.left {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

li.right {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

li#login {
  position: relative;
}

li#login form {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}

li#login:hover form {
  display: block;
}

input.login_field {
  margin: 10px;
}

#submit-div {
  text-align: center;
}

#form-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.nav-list {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

#dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

#dropdown:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.current-selection {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.in-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#search-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

#search-box:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.go-button {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.go-button:hover {
  background-color: #ff7300;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="left"><a class="fa fa-home" href="index.jsp">&nbsp;Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="left"><a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="#home">&nbsp;Carrello</a>
    </li>

    <li id="search">
      <div id="form-wrapper">
        <button class="go-button fa fa-search"></button>
        <span class="nav-list">
  <span class="current-selection">
  </span>
        <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="books-and-ebooks">Books & eBooks</option>
    <option value="audiobooks">Audiobooks</option>
    <option value="dvds">DVDs</option>
    <option value="other-resources">Other Resources</option>
    <option value="random">Random</option>
  </select>
        </span>
        <div class="in-wrap">
          <input type="text" name="query" id="search-box">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="right"><a class="fa fa-user-plus" href="">&nbsp;Signup</a>
    </li>
    <li id="login" class="right">
      <a class="fa fa-sign-in" href="">&nbsp;Login</a>
      <form id="login_form" action="login" method="post">
        <input id="login_username" class="login_field" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
        <br />
        <input id="login_password" class="login_field" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
        <br />
        <div id="submit-div">
          <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, and what if I would make the menu to not wrap?